# Error not a single group group function

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display only the top 2 buildings with their corresponding average price of a session.
This is what i have right now

```
SELECT BUILDINGLANE,SUM(SESSIONPRICE/COUNT(BUILDINGNO))
FROM BUILDING NATURAL JOIN CONFERENCESESSION 
GROUP BY BUILDINGLANE
WHERE SUM(SESSIONPRICE/COUNT(BUILDINGNO));
```

But i get the error "SQL command not properly ended" for line 3, but then if i end line 3 with a semicolon, i get this new error of "not a single-group group function" for line 1. Im not sure where im going wrong, ive tried searching about this but i havent had any luck in solving this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where clause has expression without comparison.

Comment: & `where` **always** precedes `group by` in a single select query. SELECT... FROM ... WHERE... GROUP BY... HAVING... ORDER BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Order by` instead of `Where` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT BUILDINGLANE,
               Sum(intrPrice) AS avgPrice
        FROM   (SELECT BUILDINGLANE,
                       SESSIONPRICE / Count(BUILDINGNO) AS intrPrice
                FROM   BUILDING
                       NATURAL JOIN CONFERENCESESSION
                GROUP  BY BUILDINGLANE,
                          SESSIONPRICE) a
        GROUP  BY BUILDINGLANE
        ORDER  BY avgPrice DESC) b
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 2
```

Comment: Yeah still gives me the same error :/ ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 77 Column: 8

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select * from(
    SELECT BUILDINGLANE,SUM(SESSIONPRICE)/COUNT(BUILDINGNO)
  FROM BUILDING NATURAL JOIN CONFERENCESESSION 
  GROUP BY BUILDINGLANE, BUILDINGNO
  Order by (SUM(SESSIONPRICE)/COUNT(BUILDINGNO)) desc
)
where rownum <= 2
```

Comment: Yeah i still get this error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 76 Column: 12. Really confused (you were missing a parenthesis btw)

Comment: has been add group by for you